# Solution for limitations of For Each loops?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, vb6, powerpoint

When cycling through a list of items in VBA, I use this code pattern:

```
For Each Item In ListOfItems
    ' Do something with Item
Next Item
```

However, in practical applications, I often need access to an iteration counter, the previous or next item, or I have to perform special steps for the first or last item in the list. For instance:

```
For Each Item In ListOfItems
    If Item.IsFirst Then
        ...
    End If
    Debug.Print Item.Index, Item.SomeProperty
Next Item
```

However, `.Index`  and `.IsFirst`  are not properties of the class of `Item`. Therefore, this does not work. So, my question to the community is: How can I get as close as possible to my desired code pattern?

I know that I could implement a counter with some additional code. Checking for the first item could as well be performed with some additional code. But that's not what I want. I have seen many bugs where the developer forgot to increment the counter. I want to have this out of the hands of the developer.

Likewise, I also know that I could use other types of loops, such as `Do While` or `For i=1 To ...`. That's also not what I want. I want to use THE straight-forward code pattern, which is made for cycling through a list, which in my opinion is `For Each ...`.

My own attempts to solve this led to this pattern:

```
For Each IterationItem In toIterationItems(ListOfItems)
    If IterationItem.IsFirst Then
        ...
    End If
    Debug.Print IterationItem.Index, IterationItem.Item.SomeProperty
Next IterationItem
```

This works. The function `toIterationItems` takes a `Collection` or `Dictionary` and for each element, it puts an `IterationItem` into an output `Collection`, which is handed back to the `For Each`. So, `For Each` cycles through a `Collection` of `IterationItem`s instead of the original `ListOfItems`.

While this works (I can post the code here, if desired), I am unsure, if there aren't any better approaches. My approach has some disadvantages...

Comment: Please share the code of your current solution and the list of disadvantages.

Comment: I honestly struggle to understand why you stubbornly want to use the `For Each` loop. Since I finally learned how to build arrays, the speed of execution is so enormously faster that I would never come back. Why don't you just use a dummy item and, in the loop through an array, you just assign the current value to the dummy item? In this way you get to keep the speed of the array and the counting is included.

Comment: @Bradipo, execution speed is not my concern. I agree with your opinion about the execution speed of arrays. My concern is 'usability of the programming language'. It is obvious that developers will develop faster and produce less bugs, if they can directly express their goal in the programming language.  `For Each` was invented for this purpose.

Comment: Why not just make `.First` and `.Last` properties of your Enumerable? Then you could just use `Item = ListOfItems.First`.

Comment: @Vince, yeah, I thought about that. This would be a viable alternative. For a custom Enumerable, this would work well. My current solution has the advantage that it can deal with the standard Enumerables Collection and Dictionary.

Comment: @Segner can your current solution handle Collections? `IterationItem` expects a Dictionary.

Comment: @Vince, I started with a class which expects a Dictionary. I am currently extending it to Collections and Arrays. The goal is to be able to handle any class with a Count property and an Item property. This includes custom collections. I am working on it. I just need some time, and some of the good ideas from this forum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your approach has the merit of abstracting away the need for counter management, which indeed can be a source of bugs. However, as you mention, it comes with some downsides. It introduces another level of indirection and complexity, which might confuse less experienced developers or make the code harder to maintain. Additionally, it involves creating a whole new collection just to iterate over an existing one, which is inefficient especially for large collections.

The primary alternatives in VBA would be:

1. As you mentioned, managing the counter manually. Yes, it can lead to bugs if not done carefully, but if the loop is simple and well-documented, the risks are minimal. For complex loops, an abstraction like your IterationItem might indeed be useful.
2. Using a different language feature or construct. You mentioned you want to use `For Each`, but it's worth noting that the more traditional `For` loop inherently supports accessing the index, the previous item, and the next item, and it also makes it easy to perform specific actions on the first or last item.

Here's an example of how you could use a `For` loop to do all these things:

```
Dim ListCount As Long
ListCount = ListOfItems.Count

For i = 1 To ListCount
    Dim CurrentItem As Variant
    CurrentItem = ListOfItems(i)
    
    If i = 1 Then
        ' First item
    ElseIf i = ListCount Then
        ' Last item
    Else
        ' Middle items
        Dim PreviousItem As Variant
        Dim NextItem As Variant
        PreviousItem = ListOfItems(i - 1)
        NextItem = ListOfItems(i + 1)
    End If
    
    Debug.Print i, CurrentItem.SomeProperty
Next i
```

If you prefer the readability of `For Each` and don't mind the added complexity and inefficiency, then your IterationItem approach might be the best for you. But if you want something simpler and more efficient, a `For` loop is the most natural fit for the requirements you described. It's just a matter of trade-offs between readability, simplicity, and efficiency.

Comment: Thank you, I agree with everything you wrote. You nailed the disadvantages of my approach much better than I did. As you summarized it, I am searching for the best compromise between the efficiency of the `For` and `Do While` on one side, and the readability of `For Each`. I would like to add that `For Each` has the additional advantage to not force the programmer to manage the counter variable and its boundaries. Sorry, I cannot upvote your answer because I'm lacking points...

Comment: I have posted another answer as a reply.

Comment: Thank you, I just marked this answer as 'solution'. Since this is work in progress, there is no one and only solution. I will continue developing with this approach, and will hopefully see you guys again, when I submit it to Codereview...

Comment: Hi, Code Bot! That sure is a suspicious username you have! ;-) 

Your four answers over the last day or so appear likely to be entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). Please be aware that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. 

We do hope you'll stick around and continue to be a valuable part of our community by posting *your own* quality content. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds, please do not spam my question. Before you came here, this was interesting, readable content. Now, I see your standard warning everywhere here. I think you are benevolent, but I would prefer to have your comments deleted.

Comment: @Segner I'm sorry you feel that way, but most users *do* prefer to be warned about likely-AI content.  I know the bold text is probably irritating, but a Moderator here specifically asked me to put that in there for users so that it is the first thing they see when reading the answers.  Keep in mind that answers here are seen by *many users*, and for potentially years to come, not just the person asking the question.  Thanks!

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds, peace! I see your point. In this particular case, I found the postings relevant and interesting. However, I understand that you cannot analyze every post in detail, if ChatGPT was used productively or not. Please, just be aware that such a warning not only gives valuable information, but also degrades the credibility of the entire content. That's why I was worried...

Comment: Thanks!  And hopefully we'll soon be getting back to a more typical site moderation, where the Mods will be back from strike and able to delete (at least some) AI-generated answers once again.  At that point, I'll return to just flagging (for the most part), hopefully ;-).

Answer (score 3):

As a response to @VBasic2008, I post my intermediate solution, here. This is not meant as THE solution, but only as an add-on to my question:

#### Class `IterationItem`:

```
Option Explicit

Private Type TThis
    dicParent As Dictionary
    lngIndex As Long
End Type
Private This As TThis

Public Sub Init(ByVal adicParent As Dictionary, ByVal alngIndex As Long)
    Set This.dicParent = adicParent
    This.lngIndex = alngIndex
End Sub

Public Property Get Item() As Variant
    VariantLet Item, This.dicParent.Items(This.lngIndex - 1)
End Property

Public Property Get Key() As String
    Key = This.dicParent.Keys(This.lngIndex - 1)
End Property

Public Property Get Index() As Long
    Index = This.lngIndex
End Property

Public Property Get IsFirstItem() As Boolean
    IsFirstItem = CBool(This.lngIndex = 1)
End Property
Public Property Get IsLastItem() As Boolean
    IsLastItem = CBool(This.lngIndex = This.dicParent.Count)
End Property

Public Property Get NextItem() As Variant
    VariantLet NextItem, This.dicParent.Items(This.lngIndex)
End Property

Public Property Get PrevItem() As Variant
    VariantLet PrevItem, This.dicParent.Items(This.lngIndex - 2)
End Property

Private Sub VariantLet(ByRef Destination As Variant, ByVal Source As Variant)
    If IsObject(Source) Then
        Set Destination = Source
    Else
        Destination = Source
    End If
End Sub
```

#### Function `toIterationItems`:

```
Public Function toIterationItems(ByVal InputData As Variant) As Collection
    Dim varValue As Variant, IterItem As IterationItem, Counter&
    Set toIterationItems = New Collection
    For Each varValue In InputData
        Set IterItem = New IterationItem
        Counter = Counter + 1
        IterItem.Init InputData, Counter
        toIterationItems.Add IterItem
    Next varValue
End Function
```

I don't think that is the optimal solution. I post this here only to demonstrate my direction of thinking. One disadvantage is that my solution deviates from the goal, which I described above. It also creates additional computational load.

Comment: I also don't really find a good place for the function `toIterationItems`. Currently, it located in a simple module. I'd prefer a more OOP solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, `toIterationItems()` pretty much needs to go in a module or in its own Constructor class. Factory modules seem to be the standard practice in VBA, but I agree with you that it always feels weird not having a self-contained package.

Comment: @Vince, I agree. Technically, I could make the IterItem class "PredeclaredID" and then put this function in there, but I think this would be too much of a hack. For the time being, I stick with a standard module function.

Answer (score 2):

You're welcome, and I appreciate your feedback! It's a thoughtful point about For Each reducing the risk of mismanaging the counter variable and its boundaries. That is indeed one of its strengths.

I'm not sure if there's a perfect solution that offers all the advantages of both For Each and For with none of the downsides, given the current features of VBA. It seems like you've already given this a lot of thought and come up with a pretty good compromise with your IterationItem approach.

If you're open to some slight modifications to your IterationItem approach, one potential improvement could be to use a custom iterator function instead of creating a whole new collection. This function would return one IterationItem at a time on demand, reducing the memory overhead.

Here is an example of how you could potentially create an iterator function in VBA:

```
Declare a public variable to hold the collection.
Public ListOfItems As Collection

' Iterator function.
Function NextIterationItem() As IterationItem
    Static i As Long
    
    If i < ListOfItems.Count Then
        i = i + 1
        Set NextIterationItem = New IterationItem
        Set NextIterationItem.Item = ListOfItems(i)
        NextIterationItem.Index = i
    Else
        Set NextIterationItem = Nothing
    End If
End Function
```

And here is how you could use this function in a loop:

```
Dim IterationItem As IterationItem
Set IterationItem = NextIterationItem()

Do Until IterationItem Is Nothing
    If IterationItem.Index = 1 Then
        ' First item
    End If
    Debug.Print IterationItem.Index, IterationItem.Item.SomeProperty
    Set IterationItem = NextIterationItem()
Loop
```

However, please note that this example is more illustrative than functional. VBA doesn't natively support iterators like some other languages do, and this approach relies on stateful functions and public or module-level variables, which can introduce their own complexity and potential for bugs.

So, while it's fun to explore what's possible, I would caution that sometimes the simplest and most straightforward solution is the best one, even if it's not perfect in every way. Your original For Each loop with manually managed counters might still be the best balance of simplicity, readability, and efficiency for your needs.

Comment: A `For Each...Next` loop can't handle deletion of items from a collection. How does this approach differ?

Comment: @TimothyRylatt, I don't know what Code Bot thinks about this, but I really avoid manipulating the iterated list. Especially inserting and deleting items from that list. That is asking for trouble. In my current implementation, the IterItem approach operates on a copy of the original list. Manipulations on the original list will not affect the iteration.

Comment: Hi, Code Bot! That sure is a suspicious username you have! ;-) 

Your four answers over the last day or so appear likely to be entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). Please be aware that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. 

We do hope you'll stick around and continue to be a valuable part of our community by posting *your own* quality content. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

In my work I like to use custom, strongly-typed Collection classes.  In these classes I have implemented the ideas that you are talking about.  The code shown below was created using VB6 but adapting it to VBA should be possible.  All code has been stripped down to the basics to illustrate the concepts.

The code in the Click event is typical code for adding objects to a collection.  It gets more interesting in the `ShowWidgets` method.  In this method, I loop through the collection using For Each and I have access to all the properties you mention.

**frmMain**

```
Option Explicit

Private MyWidgets As Widgets 'a custom, strongly-typed collection class
Private MyWidget As Widget

Private Sub Command1_Click()
   Set MyWidgets = New Widgets
   
   'create the initial collection
   Set MyWidget = New Widget
   MyWidget.Description = "Widget 1"
   MyWidgets.Add MyWidget

   Set MyWidget = New Widget
   MyWidget.Description = "Widget 2"
   MyWidgets.Add MyWidget

   Set MyWidget = New Widget
   MyWidget.Description = "Widget 3"
   MyWidgets.Add MyWidget
   
   ShowWidgets "Create Collection"
   
   'remove item 2
   MyWidgets.Remove 2
   
   ShowWidgets "Remove an item"

   'add a new item 2
   Set MyWidget = New Widget
   MyWidget.Description = "Widget New 2"
   MyWidgets.Add MyWidget, , , 1
   
   ShowWidgets "Add an item"
End Sub

Private Sub ShowWidgets(ByVal Message As String)
   Debug.Print Message & vbCrLf

   For Each MyWidget In MyWidgets
      Debug.Print "Index: " & MyWidget.Index & vbTab & MyWidget.Description
      Debug.Print "First: " & MyWidget.isFirstItem & vbTab & "Last: " & MyWidget.isLastItem
      Debug.Print "Previous: " & (Not MyWidget.PreviousItem Is Nothing) & vbTab & _
                  "Next: " & (Not MyWidget.NextItem Is Nothing)
   Next
   
   Debug.Print vbCrLf
End Sub
```

The challenge with getting the above code to work is setting up a communication mechanism between Widgets and a Widget so the needed information is available to the Widget.  One approach is for a Widget to have a reference back to Widgets.  This is illustrated in the `Widgets.Add` method.

**Widgets Class**

```
Option Explicit

Private m_Items As Collection

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
   Set m_Items = New Collection
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
   Set m_Items = Nothing
End Sub

Public Property Get Item(ByVal Index As Variant) As Widget
   'marked as 'Default' in Procedure Attributes
   Set Item = m_Items(Index)
End Property

Public Property Get Exists(ByVal Index As Variant) As Boolean
   On Error Resume Next

   Dim w As Widget
   
   Err.Clear
   Set w = m_Items(Index)
   Exists = (Err.Number = 0)
End Property

Public Sub Add(ByVal Item As Widget, _
               Optional ByVal Key As String, _
               Optional ByVal Before As Variant, _
               Optional ByVal After As Variant)
   Set Item.Parent = Me
               
   If Not IsMissing(After) And m_Items.Count > 0 Then
      If Not Len(Trim$(Key)) = 0 Then
         m_Items.Add Item, Key, , After
      Else
         m_Items.Add Item, , , After
      End If
   ElseIf Not IsMissing(Before) And m_Items.Count > 0 Then
      If Not Len(Trim$(Key)) = 0 Then
         m_Items.Add Item, Key, Before
      Else
         m_Items.Add Item, , Before
      End If
   Else
      If Not Len(Trim$(Key)) = 0 Then
         m_Items.Add Item, Key
      Else
         m_Items.Add Item
      End If
   End If
   
   RenumberItems
End Sub

Public Sub Remove(ByVal Index As Variant)
   m_Items.Remove Index
   RenumberItems
End Sub

Public Property Get Count() As Long
   Count = m_Items.Count
End Property

Public Property Get NewEnum() As IUnknown
   'marked as '-4' and 'Hide' in Procedure Attributes
   Set NewEnum = m_Items.[_NewEnum]
End Property

Private Sub RenumberItems()
   Dim i As Integer
   
   For i = 1 To m_Items.Count
      m_Items(i).Index = i
   Next
End Sub
```

With the reference set, a Widget can implement the needed methods.

**Widget Class**

```
Option Explicit

Private m_Parent As Widgets

Private m_Index As Long
Private m_Description As String

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
'
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
   Set m_Parent = Nothing
End Sub

Public Property Set Parent(ByVal Value As Widgets)
   Set m_Parent = Value
End Property

Public Property Let Index(ByVal Value As Long)
   m_Index = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Index() As Long
   Index = m_Index
End Property

Public Property Get isFirstItem() As Boolean
   isFirstItem = (m_Index = 1)
End Property

Public Property Get isLastItem() As Boolean
   isLastItem = (m_Index = m_Parent.Count)
End Property

Public Function NextItem() As Widget
   If m_Index < m_Parent.Count Then
      Set NextItem = m_Parent(m_Index + 1)
   Else
      Set NextItem = Nothing
   End If
End Function

Public Function PreviousItem() As Widget
   If m_Index > 1 Then
      Set PreviousItem = m_Parent(m_Index - 1)
   Else
      Set PreviousItem = Nothing
   End If
End Function

Public Property Let Description(ByVal Value As String)
   m_Description = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Description() As String
   Description = m_Description
End Property
```

**EDIT**

The solution can be generalized for strings, integers, or objects without too much trouble.  The code in frmMain is pretty much like it was originally.

**frmMain**

```
Option Explicit

Private MyItems As BetterCollection
Private MyItem As IterationItem

Private Sub Command1_Click()
   'create the collection with strings
   Set MyItems = New BetterCollection
   Set MyItem = New IterationItem
   MyItem.Item = "String 1"
   MyItems.Add MyItem

   'or create the collection with integers
   Set MyItems = New BetterCollection
   Set MyItem = New IterationItem
   MyItem.Item = 1000
   MyItems.Add MyItem

   'or create the collection with objects
   Dim MyWidget As Widget
   Set MyWidget = New Widget
   MyWidget.Description = "My Widget 1"

   Set MyItems = New BetterCollection
   Set MyItem = New IterationItem
   MyItem.Item = MyWidget
   MyItems.Add MyItem

   '.
   '.
   '.

   'and then looping for objects
   For Each MyItem In MyItems
      Debug.Print "Index: " & MyItem.Index & vbTab & MyItem.Item.Description
   Next

   'or looping for strings or integers
   For Each MyItem In MyItems
      Debug.Print "Index: " & MyItem.Index & vbTab & MyItem.Item
   Next
End Sub
```

Besides renaming the classes, the only significant mods were to the original Widget class (now named IterationItem).  I took the liberty of using your VariantLet method.

**BetterCollection Class**

```
Option Explicit

Private m_Items As Collection

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
   Set m_Items = New Collection
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
   Set m_Items = Nothing
End Sub

Public Property Get Item(ByVal Index As Variant) As IterationItem
   'marked as 'Default' in Procedure Attributes
   Set Item = m_Items(Index)
End Property

Public Property Get Exists(ByVal Index As Variant) As Boolean
   On Error Resume Next

   Dim Item As IterationItem
   
   Err.Clear
   Set Item = m_Items(Index)
   Exists = (Err.Number = 0)
End Property

Public Sub Add(ByVal Item As IterationItem, _
               Optional ByVal Key As String, _
               Optional ByVal Before As Variant, _
               Optional ByVal After As Variant)
   Set Item.Parent = Me
               
   If Not IsMissing(After) And m_Items.Count > 0 Then
      If Not Len(Trim$(Key)) = 0 Then
         m_Items.Add Item, Key, , After
      Else
         m_Items.Add Item, , , After
      End If
   ElseIf Not IsMissing(Before) And m_Items.Count > 0 Then
      If Not Len(Trim$(Key)) = 0 Then
         m_Items.Add Item, Key, Before
      Else
         m_Items.Add Item, , Before
      End If
   Else
      If Not Len(Trim$(Key)) = 0 Then
         m_Items.Add Item, Key
      Else
         m_Items.Add Item
      End If
   End If
   
   RenumberItems
End Sub

Public Sub Remove(ByVal Index As Variant)
   m_Items.Remove Index
   RenumberItems
End Sub

Public Property Get Count() As Long
   Count = m_Items.Count
End Property

Public Property Get NewEnum() As IUnknown
   'marked as '-4' and 'Hide' in Procedure Attributes
   Set NewEnum = m_Items.[_NewEnum]
End Property

Private Sub RenumberItems()
   Dim i As Integer
   
   For i = 1 To m_Items.Count
      m_Items(i).Index = i
   Next
End Sub
```

**IterationItem Class**

```
Option Explicit

Private m_Parent As BetterCollection
Private m_Item As Variant
Private m_Index As Long

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
'
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
   Set m_Parent = Nothing
End Sub

Public Property Set Parent(ByVal Value As BetterCollection)
   Set m_Parent = Value
End Property

Public Property Let Item(ByVal Value As Variant)
   VariantLet m_Item, Value
End Property

Public Property Get Item() As Variant
   VariantLet Item, m_Item
End Property

Public Property Let Index(ByVal Value As Long)
   m_Index = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Index() As Long
   Index = m_Index
End Property

Public Property Get isFirstItem() As Boolean
   isFirstItem = (Me.Index = 1)
End Property

Public Property Get isLastItem() As Boolean
   isLastItem = (Me.Index = m_Parent.Count)
End Property

Public Function NextItem() As IterationItem
   If Me.Index < m_Parent.Count Then
      Set NextItem = m_Parent(Me.Index + 1)
   Else
      Set NextItem = Nothing
   End If
End Function

Public Function PreviousItem() As IterationItem
   If Me.Index > 1 Then
      Set PreviousItem = m_Parent(Me.Index - 1)
   Else
      Set PreviousItem = Nothing
   End If
End Function

Private Sub VariantLet(ByRef Destination As Variant, ByVal Source As Variant)
    If IsObject(Source) Then
       Set Destination = Source
    Else
       Destination = Source
    End If
End Sub
```

Hopefully this code can provide you with some ideas.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution! Your For Each loop is exactly the way I desired it. Your Widget class corresponds directly to my class IterItem. Our approaches are quite similar. Something, I do not understand on your solution: How can this be generalized, i.e. how can it be used to iterate over a collection of strings, integers or ranges? Would I have to rewrite the Widget class?

Comment: Yes, you would need to rewrite the Widget class.  I will update my answer to show how  to generalize the solution.

Comment: Brian, we seem to think alike. Your extension goes a quite similar path as my own extensions. With some interesting differences. I will come back later with more feedback...

Comment: Brian, I would love to see some comments on my last post ;-)

Answer (score 2):

As a response to Brian M Stafford, I am sharing my improved implementation. I want to discuss similarities and differences of our approaches. Maybe, we can find something better, together. The common goal is to be able to do something like this:

### Goal

```
For Each Item In MyCollectionOrDictionary
   If Item.IsFirstItem Then
       ...
   End If
   Debug.Print Item.Key, Item.Value, Item.Index, Item.NextValue
Next Item
```

Standard `For Each` loops neither allow access to an index, nor to the next value, nor do they provide something like `IsFirstItem`. Obviously, it is possible to achieve this with additional code, but that is not what I want, as such code is the source of many bugs in the everyday business of developers. I also do not want to replace the `For Each` loop with a standard `For` loop or a `Do` loop. The `Do` loop is always a choice as it the most generic type of loop, but for iterating through items of a list, I consider `For Each` loop the first choice.

Brian’s and my ideas for an enhanced `For Each` loop have in common that both prepare the list to enable the enhanced looping. The items are replaced by instances of a new class called `IterationItem`:
[image: Before and After]

The `IterationItem` objects then provide access to the desired properties `IsFirstItem`, `Index`, `NextItem`, but also the original `Value` and `Key`.

### Class IterationItem

```
Option Explicit

Private Type TThis
    Key As String
    Value As Variant
    Index As Long
    PrevItem As IterationItem
    NextItem As IterationItem
End Type
Private This As TThis

Public Sub Init(ByVal List As Variant, ByVal Index As Long, ByVal PrevItem As IterationItem, ByVal NextItem As IterationItem)
    Select Case TypeName(List)
    Case "Dictionary"
        This.Key = List.Keys()(Index - 1)
        VariantLet This.Value, List.Items()(Index - 1)
    Case "Collection"
        This.Key = CStr(Index)
        VariantLet This.Value, List.Item(Index)
    Case Else 'Arrays
        If IsArray(List) Then  ' TODO: Assert number of dimensions. Currently, we assume only 1 dimension. Throws, if there are more than one.
            This.Key = CStr(Index)
            VariantLet This.Value, List(Index - 1 + LBound(List))
        Else
            Err.Raise vbObjectError, "IterationItem", "Unexpected list type:" & TypeName(List)
        End If
    End Select
    This.Index = Index
    Set This.PrevItem = PrevItem
    Set This.NextItem = NextItem
End Sub

Public Property Get Value() As Variant
    VariantLet Value, This.Value
End Property
Public Property Get NextValue() As Variant
    VariantLet NextValue, This.NextItem.Value
End Property
Public Property Get PrevValue() As Variant
    VariantLet PrevValue, This.PrevItem.Value
End Property

Public Property Get Key() As String
    Key = This.Key
End Property
Public Property Get Index() As Long
    Index = This.Index
End Property

Public Property Get IsFirstItem() As Boolean
    IsFirstItem = CBool(This.PrevItem Is Nothing)
End Property
Public Property Get IsLastItem() As Boolean
    IsLastItem = CBool(This.NextItem Is Nothing)
End Property

Private Sub VariantLet(ByRef Destination As Variant, ByVal Source As Variant)
    If IsObject(Source) Then
        Set Destination = Source
    Else
        Destination = Source
    End If
End Sub
```

The following function performs the conversion from ‘Before’ to ‘After’.

### Function ToIterationItems

```
Option Explicit

'Convert a List of items into a standard VBA Collection.
'This Collection is being filled with IterationItem objects,
'which replace the original items.
'Purpose: allow 'enhanced' For Each looping over the items.
'List typically is a Collection or Dictionary, but can be any
'object with a Count property. Arrays are accepted as well.
'@param {Variant} - List: The container of the items.
'@returns {Collection} - Collection of IterationItem objects.
''Usage:
'Dim IterItem as IterationItem
'For Each IterItem In ToIterationItems(MyCollection)
'   If IterItem.IsFirstItem Then
'       ...
'   End If
'   Debug.Print IterItem.Key, IterItem.Value, IterItem.Index
'Next IterItem
Public Function ToIterationItems(ByVal List As Variant) As VBA.Collection
    Set ToIterationItems = New VBA.Collection
    
    Dim NoItems As Long
    If IsObject(List) Then
        NoItems = List.Count  ' Throws, if there is no Count property
    Else
        NoItems = UBound(List) - LBound(List) + 1 ' Throws, if List is not an array
    End If
    If NoItems = 0 Then Exit Function
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To NoItems
        ToIterationItems.Add New IterationItem
    Next i
    
    ' Build a chained list of IterationItem instances
    Dim CurrItem As IterationItem, NextItem As IterationItem, PrevItem As IterationItem
    Set NextItem = ToIterationItems.Item(1)
    For i = 1 To NoItems
        Set PrevItem = CurrItem
        Set CurrItem = NextItem
        If i < NoItems Then
            Set NextItem = ToIterationItems.Item(i + 1)
        Else
            Set NextItem = Nothing
        End If
        CurrItem.Init List, i, PrevItem, NextItem
    Next i
End Function
```

### Usage

```
Dim IterItem as IterationItem
For Each IterItem In ToIterationItems(MyCollectionOrDictionary)
   If IterItem.IsFirstItem Then
       ...
   End If
   Debug.Print IterItem.Key, IterItem.Value, IterItem.Index
Next IterItem
```

This usage is close to what I set as my goal above. However, I need the function `ToIterationItems` be called in the `For Each` statement. I am using this pattern already for some weeks, now, and I find that it makes my code clearer and better readable.

### Discussion

In Brian’s solution (see his answer), the usage in the `For Each` loop is even closer to the goal. He does not need the function `ToIterationItems`, but he must put some extra effort when adding the items to the collection.

Brian uses a strongly typed custom `Collection` class to hold the `IterationItem` instances. I use the standard VBA `Collection` class.

Brian’s `IterationItem` instances store a reference to the parent `Collection`. Some of his `IterationItem` properties retrieve their values from there. I only copy the `Key` and `Value` of each item. This way, my approach can deal with arrays.

Comment: I really don't have any further suggestions.  It looks like you have a well thought out solution.